# Diplaying activity details in a data table in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, dt, ggplotly

When I run this R shiny script below, I get two plots with a chart for activity path derived from the patients dataset of the bupaR library called trace explorer on the left and a data table to display the activity/trace details. The chart on the left is such,that we observe various paths with sequence of horizontal traces of activities which occur one after the other. When clicked on any box in a particular trace, the trace details are presented on the right table. My requirement is that, when clicked on any box in a particular trace, the "y" or fourth column value should be taken dynamically, and I should get just one column displaying all the activities that occur in the trace. E.g. in the attached image, when clicked anywhere on the bottom most path, I should get one column with activities "Registration", "Triage and Assessment". Please help and thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(devtools)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(proto)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gapminder)
library(stringr)
library(broom)
library(mnormt)
library(DT)
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)
library(scales)
library(splitstackshape)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "My Chart"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(



box(title = "Data Path", status = "primary",height = "455" ,solidHeader = T,
    plotlyOutput("sankey_plot")),

box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", height = "455",solidHeader 
= T, 
     dataTableOutput("sankey_table"))
)
)
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({

tr <- data.frame(traces(patients, output_traces = T, output_cases = F))
tr.df <- cSplit(tr, "trace", ",")
tr.df$af_percent <-
  percent(tr.df$absolute_frequency/sum(tr.df$absolute_frequency))
pos <- c(1,4:ncol(tr.df))
tr.df <- tr.df[,..pos]
tr.df <- melt(tr.df, id.vars = c("trace_id","af_percent"))
mp1 = ggplot(data = tr.df, aes(x = variable,y = trace_id, fill = value,
                               label = value,
                               text=paste("Variable:",variable,"<br> Trace 
ID:",trace_id,"<br> Value:",value,"<br> Actuals:",af_percent))) +
  geom_tile(colour = "white") +
  geom_text(colour = "white", fontface = "bold", size = 2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.value="transparent") +
  theme(legend.position="none") + labs(x = "Traces", y = "Activities")
ggplotly(mp1, tooltip=c("text"), height = 380, width = 605)
})
output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
tp2 = event_data("plotly_click")
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Trace Chart]

**Second Part**:

```
library(lubridate)
patients1 <<- arrange(patients, patient)
patients2 <<- patients1 %>% arrange(patient, time)
patients3 <<- patients2 %>%
group_by(patient) %>%
mutate(diff_in_sec = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") - 
lag(as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
default=first(as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))))%>%
mutate(diff_in_hours = as.numeric(diff_in_sec/3600)) %>% mutate(diff_in_days 
= as.numeric(diff_in_hours/24))
```

Upon running this code above, you get the patients data from the bupaR library such that there are 500 cases in the data given under the "patient" column, the activities in every case are in the "handling" column and are arranged in ascending order of the time of their occurrence. My requirement is that I want to compare the "value" column obtained from the previous solution in the DT table and compare with 'unique(handling)' i.e. unique activities in every  case "patient" in the patients3 dataset. The cases where the "value" column finds an exact match, I want to display the entire corresponding rows in the DT table. E.g. when clicked anywhere on the bottom most path, the trace with activities "Registration", "Triage and Assessment", the "value" column should be compared with unique of activities in every case from 1 to 500, if match found i.e. cases with activities "Registration", "Triage and Assessment",  those cases with corresponding rows should be displayed, similarly for all traces. Thank you and please help.

**Third Part**:

I want to fix the data table in the second box by giving it a suitable pageLength, such that it should not overshoot from below and from the right. Please find the consolidated code below, some possible syntax I know to integrate in the plot to achieve this are as follows:

**Possible syntax**:

```
datatable(Data, options = list(
    searching = TRUE,
    pageLength = 9
  ))
**and**

box( title = "Case Details", status = "primary", height = "575",solidHeader 
= T,width = "6", 
div(DT::dataTableOutput("Data_table"), style = "font-size: 84%; width: 
65%"))

**Here is the consolidated final code to be updated**

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "My Chart"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
box(title = "Data Path", status = "primary",height = "455" ,solidHeader = T,
    plotlyOutput("sankey_plot")),

box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", solidHeader 
     = T, 
     dataTableOutput("sankey_table"),
     width = 6)
 )
 )
 server <- function(input, output) 
 { 
 #Plot for Trace Explorer
 dta <- reactive({
 tr <- data.frame(traces(patients, output_traces = T, output_cases = F))
 tr.df <- cSplit(tr, "trace", ",")
 tr.df$af_percent <-
  percent(tr.df$absolute_frequency/sum(tr.df$absolute_frequency))
 pos <- c(1,4:ncol(tr.df))
 tr.df <- tr.df[,..pos]
 tr.df <- melt(tr.df, id.vars = c("trace_id","af_percent"))
 tr.df
 })
 patients10 <- reactive({
 patients11 <- arrange(patients, patient)
 patients12 <- patients1 %>% arrange(patient, time,handling_id)
 patients12 %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),diff_in_sec = 
  time - lag(time)) %>% 
  mutate(diff_in_sec = ifelse(is.na(diff_in_sec),0,diff_in_sec)) %>% 
  mutate(diff_in_hours = as.numeric(diff_in_sec/3600)) %>% 
  mutate(diff_in_days = as.numeric(diff_in_hours/24))
  })
  output$trace_plot <- renderPlotly({
  mp1 = ggplot(data = dta(), aes(x = variable,y = trace_id, fill = value,
                               label = value,
                               text=paste("Variable:",variable,"<br> Trace 
                                          ID:",trace_id,"<br> 
  Value:",value,"<br> Actuals:",af_percent))) +
  geom_tile(colour = "white") +
  geom_text(colour = "white", fontface = "bold", size = 2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.value="transparent") +
  theme(legend.position="none") + labs(x = "Traces", y = "Activities")
  ggplotly(mp1, tooltip=c("text"), height = 516, width = 605)
  })
  output$trace_table <- renderDataTable({
  req(event_data("plotly_click"))
  Values <- dta() %>% 
  filter(trace_id == event_data("plotly_click")[["y"]]) %>% 
  select(value)
  valueText <- paste0(Values[[1]] %>% na.omit(),collapse = "")
  agg <- aggregate(handling~patient, data = patients10(), FUN = function(y)
  {paste0(unique(y),collapse = "")})
  currentPatient <- agg$patient[agg$handling == valueText]
  patients10() %>%
  filter(patient %in% currentPatient)
  })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please help.
[image: DT table capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the package dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
```

since you already had done all the hard work catching the events from plotly I changed the server following moving the calculation of `tr.df` into seperate reactive so that I could use it again for the table and the filter after the y value the plotly event.

```
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
  dta <- reactive({
    tr <- data.frame(traces(patients, output_traces = T, output_cases = F))
    tr.df <- cSplit(tr, "trace", ",")
    tr.df$af_percent <-
      percent(tr.df$absolute_frequency/sum(tr.df$absolute_frequency))
    pos <- c(1,4:ncol(tr.df))
    tr.df <- tr.df[,..pos]
    tr.df <- melt(tr.df, id.vars = c("trace_id","af_percent"))
    tr.df
  })

  output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({


    mp1 = ggplot(data = dta(), aes(x = variable,y = trace_id, fill = value,
                                   label = value,
                                   text=paste("Variable:",variable,"<br> Trace 
ID:",trace_id,"<br> Value:",value,"<br> Actuals:",af_percent))) +
      geom_tile(colour = "white") +
      geom_text(colour = "white", fontface = "bold", size = 2) +
      scale_fill_discrete(na.value="transparent") +
      theme(legend.position="none") + labs(x = "Traces", y = "Activities")
    ggplotly(mp1, tooltip=c("text"), height = 380, width = 605)
  })
  output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
    req(event_data("plotly_click"))
    dta() %>% 
      filter(trace_id == event_data("plotly_click")[["y"]]) %>% 
      select(value)

  })
}
```

** Second Part **
For the server.r did I add the followning reactive function

```
patients3 <- reactive({
    patients1 <- arrange(patients, patient)
    patients2 <- patients1 %>% arrange(patient, time,handling_id)
    patients2 %>%
      group_by(patient) %>%
      mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),diff_in_sec = time - lag(time)) %>% 
      mutate(diff_in_sec = ifelse(is.na(diff_in_sec),0,diff_in_sec)) %>% 
      mutate(diff_in_hours = as.numeric(diff_in_sec/3600)) %>% 
      mutate(diff_in_days = as.numeric(diff_in_hours/24))

  })
```

and changed the `renderDataTable` accordingly

```
output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
    req(event_data("plotly_click"))
    Values <- dta() %>% 
      filter(trace_id == event_data("plotly_click")[["y"]]) %>% 
      select(value)
    patient <- patients3()[["patient"]] %>% unique()
    result = NULL
    for(p in patient){
      handlings <- patients3() %>% 
        filter(patient == p) %>% 
        `$`(handling) %>% 
        unique()
      if(sum(!is.na(Values)) == length(handlings) &&
         all(handlings %in% Values[[1]])){
        result <- rbind(result,
                        patients3() %>% 
                          filter(patient == p))
      }
    }
    result
  })
```

Since your new table is a lot bigger would I also change the box for the table to something like this

```
box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", solidHeader 
         = T, 
         dataTableOutput("sankey_table"),
         width = 8)
```

all in all together it looks something like this

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Chart"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 0
  ),
  dashboardBody(



    box(title = "Data Path", status = "primary",height = "455" ,solidHeader = T,
        plotlyOutput("sankey_plot")),

    box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", solidHeader 
         = T, 
         dataTableOutput("sankey_table"),
         width = 8)
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
  dta <- reactive({
    tr <- data.frame(traces(patients, output_traces = T, output_cases = F))
    tr.df <- cSplit(tr, "trace", ",")
    tr.df$af_percent <-
      percent(tr.df$absolute_frequency/sum(tr.df$absolute_frequency))
    pos <- c(1,4:ncol(tr.df))
    tr.df <- tr.df[,..pos]
    tr.df <- melt(tr.df, id.vars = c("trace_id","af_percent"))
    tr.df
  })
  patients3 <- reactive({
    patients1 <- arrange(patients, patient)
    patients2 <- patients1 %>% arrange(patient, time,handling_id)
    patients2 %>%
      group_by(patient) %>%
      mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),diff_in_sec = time - lag(time)) %>% 
      mutate(diff_in_sec = ifelse(is.na(diff_in_sec),0,diff_in_sec)) %>% 
      mutate(diff_in_hours = as.numeric(diff_in_sec/3600)) %>% 
      mutate(diff_in_days = as.numeric(diff_in_hours/24))

  })
  output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({


    mp1 = ggplot(data = dta(), aes(x = variable,y = trace_id, fill = value,
                                   label = value,
                                   text=paste("Variable:",variable,"<br> Trace 
ID:",trace_id,"<br> Value:",value,"<br> Actuals:",af_percent))) +
      geom_tile(colour = "white") +
      geom_text(colour = "white", fontface = "bold", size = 2) +
      scale_fill_discrete(na.value="transparent") +
      theme(legend.position="none") + labs(x = "Traces", y = "Activities")
    ggplotly(mp1, tooltip=c("text"), height = 380, width = 605)
  })
  output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
    req(event_data("plotly_click"))
    Values <- dta() %>% 
      filter(trace_id == event_data("plotly_click")[["y"]]) %>% 
      select(value)
    patient <- patients3()[["patient"]] %>% unique()
    result = NULL
    for(p in patient){
      handlings <- patients3() %>% 
        filter(patient == p) %>% 
        `$`(handling) %>% 
        unique()
      if(sum(!is.na(Values)) == length(handlings) &&
         all(handlings %in% Values[[1]])){
        result <- rbind(result,
                        patients3() %>% 
                          filter(patient == p))
      }
    }
    result
  })
}
```

Hope this helps!

** Speed Up **

the foor loop in the calculations of the datatable is taking quite  some time here is a speed up for that calculation

```
output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
    req(event_data("plotly_click"))
    Values <- dta() %>% 
      filter(trace_id == event_data("plotly_click")[["y"]]) %>% 
      select(value)

    valueText <- paste0(Values[[1]] %>% na.omit(),collapse = "")
    agg <- aggregate(handling~patient, data = patients3(), FUN = function(y){paste0(unique(y),collapse = "")})

    currentPatient <- agg$patient[agg$handling == valueText]

    patients3() %>%
      filter(patient %in% currentPatient) %>% 
        DT::datatable(options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Straight to the point it is. I will surely upvote this, however there is an addon requirement to this, this was just a subset, I seek your help on the same, should I ask here in the comment, else you want me to put it as a new query?

Comment: you can pu it here in the comments or even better update your orignial question with the addon. No need to place a new query

Comment: thank you so much for replying, I updated the question as you suggested, please check.

Comment: so have changed my answer to solve you addon as well

Comment: Hey, small request, can you please edit and paste a consolidated code, this one is a little tricky to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159663/discussion-between-ashmin-kaul-and-bertil-nestorius).

Comment: Hi, I tried your script on another eventlog data which has lesser columns than the original eventlog above, I was able to create a trace chart but data is not getting displayed, Please help me here with this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920689/displaying-data-in-the-chart-based-on-plotly-click-in-r-shiny/47921511#47921511