# Displaying the table details from sankey chart in R shiny

Tags: r, plotly, shiny, sankey-diagram, ggplotly

The script below works on the patients data from bupaR package,and creates a sankey plot listing the relation between a resource from the "employee" column with the activity he is involved in from the "handling" column in the patients data. Besides the plot there is a data table available from DT which gives details of every sankey plot path when clicked. I want a functionality such that when I click on any path, say path connecting "r1" employee and "Registration" handling activity, I want all the rows from patients data with both these fields available in the plot besides, similarly for all other paths, this should be dynamic as I shall apply the functionality on larger datasets. Attaching the snapshot for reference. Thanks and please help.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(devtools)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(proto)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gapminder)
library(stringr)
library(broom)
library(mnormt)
library(DT)
library(bupaR)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Sankey Chart"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
box(title = "Sankey Chart", status = "primary",height = "455" ,solidHeader = T,
    plotlyOutput("sankey_plot")),

box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", height = "455",solidHeader = T, 
     dataTableOutput("sankey_table"))
 )
 )
 server <- function(input, output) 
 { 
 output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({
 sankeyData <- patients %>% 
  group_by(employee,handling) %>% 
  count()
 sankeyNodes <- list(label = c(sankeyData$employee,sankeyData$handling))
 trace2 <- list(
  domain = list(
    x = c(0, 1), 
    y = c(0, 1)
  ), 
  link = list(
    label = paste0("Case",1:nrow(sankeyData)), 
    source = sapply(sankeyData$employee,function(e) {which(e == 
  sankeyNodes$label) }, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
    target = sapply(sankeyData$handling,function(e) {which(e == 
  sankeyNodes$label) }, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
    value = sankeyData$n
  ), 
  node = list(label = sankeyNodes$label), 
  type = "sankey"
  )
  data2 <- list(trace2)
  p <- plot_ly()
  p <- add_trace(p, domain=trace2$domain, link=trace2$link, 
               node=trace2$node, type=trace2$type)
  p
  })
  output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
  d <- event_data("plotly_click")
  d
  })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I interpreted the output from event_data as such that `pointNumber` is the index of the link but I might be wrong here. Any way this is my Solution and it works for this data

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(devtools)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(proto)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gapminder)
library(stringr)
library(broom)
library(mnormt)
library(DT)
library(bupaR)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Sankey Chart"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 0
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Sankey Chart", status = "primary",height = "455" ,solidHeader = T,
        plotlyOutput("sankey_plot")),

    box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", height = "455",solidHeader = T, 
         dataTableOutput("sankey_table"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
  sankeyData <- reactive({
    sankeyData <- patients %>% 
      group_by(employee,handling) %>% 
      count()
    sankeyNodes <- list(label = c(sankeyData$employee,sankeyData$handling) %>% unique())
    trace2 <- list(
      domain = list(
        x = c(0, 1), 
        y = c(0, 1)
      ), 
      link = list(
        label = paste0("Case",1:nrow(sankeyData)), 
        source = sapply(sankeyData$employee,function(e) {which(e == 
                                                                 sankeyNodes$label) }, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
        target = sapply(sankeyData$handling,function(e) {which(e == 
                                                                 sankeyNodes$label) }, USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
        value = sankeyData$n
      ), 
      node = list(label = sankeyNodes$label), 
      type = "sankey"
    )
    trace2
  })

  output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({
    trace2 <- sankeyData()
    p <- plot_ly()
    p <- add_trace(p, domain=trace2$domain, link=trace2$link, 
                   node=trace2$node, type=trace2$type)
    p
  })
  output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    req(d)
    trace2 <- sankeyData()
    sIdx <-  trace2$link$source[d$pointNumber+1]
    Source <- trace2$node$label[sIdx + 1 ]
    tIdx <- trace2$link$target[d$pointNumber+1]
    Target <- trace2$node$label[tIdx+1]
    patients %>% filter(employee == Source & handling == Target)


  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

hope it helps!

Comment: works perfectly, however, this point index, I had also implemented in a little different manner, my question is if I implement this with say 1000 cases and 1000 activities, where multiple cases are linked to multiple activities, would I get a working solution?

Comment: I believe so. But not 100% sure. I tried a small example with cross references and this solution seams to work.

Comment: Sure, let me check this.

Comment: Hey, I tried your code but when I run your code on a different data with two columns resource  and activity, the plot gives an error: "non-numeric argument to binary operator". Take a simple example like resource <- c("A","B","C") and activity <- c("m","n","o") and a data frame a12 <- data.frame(resource,activity). Please help.

Comment: I am still facing issues, please help.

Comment: I will look into it as soon as my computer is up and running again. At the moment it won't even boot.

Comment: in your code above, "employee" and "handling" column, when I replace the columns with some other two columns from other dataset, it just does not run, please help me when your issue gets resolved.

Comment: @AshminKaul I think the problem could be with this line

`sankeyNodes <- list(label = c(sankeyData$employee,sankeyData$handling))`

try changing it to

`sankeyNodes <- list(label = c(sankeyData$employee,sankeyData$handling) %>% unique() )`

It is also important that their are no circles in the graph you cant have something like `a -> b` anf the at the same time have `b -> a`

hope this helps

Comment: it works fine now, thanks a ton, could you please explain what was the issue, and what is unique doing here?

Comment: I need your severe help with another eventlog data in which I need requirement. Your code is perfect to the point but need your help with on-click functionality. Thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433655/diplaying-activity-details-in-a-data-table-in-r-shiny/47436197?noredirect=1#comment81860625_47436197